# How to show content of metaboxes in preview mode

Tags: wordpress

In Wordpress I have custom template that I apply to pages. This template has number of metaboxes where user can add values. This works fine when post is published, I cannot figure out however the way on how to make content of these metaboxes to show in preview when I click "Preview" button from page editing view in wordpress admin. If someone could point me to right direction that would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
<?php if(is_preview() ) : ?>
//some logical part here
<?php endif; ?>
```